# Synonym or another way to say 'From theory to practice' or 'From policy to implementation'

Tags: synonyms

I'm trying to come up with a thesis title looking at how policy is implemented. It seems, however, as though 'From Theory to Practice' or 'Turning Policy into Practice' or 'From Policy to Implementation' (or variations of this) are used quite frequently, and I'm struggling to think of something more unique. Any ideas? One day before submission and my brain has been reduced to mush.

Answer (score 0):

From "theory to practice" seems pretty good to me, though a cliché.

Two phrases come to mind: **"from plan to action"** or **"from blueprint to reality"**

Comment: Thanks for the input; I like your suggestions. I'd also been thinking about something like 'Transcending Policy' followed by a more descriptive subtitle.

Comment: @Uhura I would be careful with _Transcending Policy_ as a thesis title. If I saw that, I would expect the thesis to be about something like Sartre or Kant or exegesis… basically philosophy or religion, not something about how policies are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

May be "**A bridge between knowledge and know-how**"